# ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM way of ServiceLocator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I'm a little confused with IServiceLocator, IMvcServiceLocator, IDependencyResolver, etc...

What is the ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM way of locating services?

All I need is to access something like

```
T Resolve<T>();
T Resolve<T>(string key);
```

from anywhere (including another assembly).

EDIT: example

My web app has a kind of modular architecture. Themes are one aspect of modules. Each theme is an individual class library. It's not possible to know what services a theme needs. E.g. some view might display a tag cloud widget and that widget needs an instance of TagRepository.

Currently I'm using Windsor for IoC and I could expose that container for modules. But I don't really want to make every module depend on Windsor. I would like to know if there's a solution in standard Mvc library since modules need a reference to that anyway.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I've asked 10 questions. 4 of them : 0 answers, another 4: 1 answer, last 2: 2 answers. How can I accept nonexistent answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net Mvc doesn't have it's own DI container. You would have to implement IDependencyResolver. Take a look at this question: [Castle Windsor Dependency Resolver for MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140860/castle-windsor-dependency-resolver-for-mvc-3-rc)

Comment: IDependencyResolver doesn't have a method to get service by name/key. Some beta version had IMvcServiceLocator and MvcServiceLocator http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt1-introduction.html but those don't exist in RTM. So there isn't an exact substitutions for them?

Comment: I don't remember if those interfaces were the same...If you've read part 5, he stated: For developers porting code from MVC 3 Preview 1 to MVC 3 Beta, this interface replaces IMvcServiceLocator.